# Symbolic integration of Mittag-Leffler function in R

Tags: r, integral

I'm trying to solve the following integral from `0` to `t`, where the value of `t` is not known but is surely less than infinite of the following function:

```
e^(x*s)*x^(b-1)mlf(-x^b,b,b) dx
```

where `s` is again a real valued variable of which the value is unknown and `b` is the parameter of the Mittag-Leffler function, such that `0<b<1`. I have tried with "Ryacas" but whenever I try to define a variable as symbolic, let say for example:

```
x<- Sym("x")
```

the function `"Sym"` is not found thus I cannot even try to integrate the function.

Any suggestions will be really appreciated!

Comment: hi Laura. Sym() is not in the base library of R. did you install and load the required library before calling Sym(). maybe you can show your snippet code?

Comment: Hi Laura. To make x a yacas symbol you do `x <- ysym("x")`. You can read the package documentation to find out more. Try `vignette("getting-started", package = "Ryacas")`

Comment: Thank  you! at least it recognise the variable. Although the integration of the function is not possible. I might think is because the mittag-leffler function implemented in the mittaglefflerR package is avaible only for numerical evaluation? Any way I try the computation of the integral of e^(x*s)*x*(b-1) and the result is the function itself, does that mean that it cannot be analytically evaluated?

Comment: I'm sure there's an error somewhere since I run the same integral in matlab and it gave me primitive. Unfortunatelly when it comes to the mittag-leffler function I get the same bug in matlab as well, I'm guessing the ml-function are implemented just for numerical analysis